# Why are explicit constructors not matching when list-initializing function arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, language-lawyer, list-initialization

To illustrate the issue, let's consider those two simple definitions, `Bar` being a user type with explicit constructor from int:

```
struct Bar
{
    explicit Bar(int a)
    {}
};

void f(Bar)
{}
```

Now, as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) states:

> direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit
>   constructors are considered)

We can initialize an instance this way

`Bar b1{5};`

Yet, this is a compilation error to call the function this way

`f({5});`

It would still naively look like direct list initialization of the `Bar` argument of `f`, plus one could argue that explicitely using braces around the argument makes it... explicit.

What is the rationale for disallowing usage of the explicit constructor for list-initialized function arguments ?

### Edit

The linked page is indeed saying that this is not direct-list-initialization in this situation. Yet, in the spirit of the question, what would be the rationale to design the language rules so this case is a copy-list-init rather than a direct-list-init ?

Comment: `f({5})` is copy-list-initialization.

Comment: @T.C. You are right, this is point 7) in the page linked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because for passing function argument, it's not direct-list-initialization, but [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization); only non-explicit constructors may be called.

> ```
> function( { arg1, arg2, ... } ) ; (7)
> ```
>
> - copy-list-initialization (only non-explicit constructors may be called)
>
> 7) in a function call expression, with braced-init-list used as an
>   argument and list-initialization initializes the function parameter

Note that before C++11 (i.e. in spite of the C++11 feature list initialization), passing an argument to a function by value is always regarged as [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not direct initialization.

Comment: "For copy-list-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered." Nope.

Comment: @T.C. Is it different with "only non-explicit constructors may be called" ? Am I missing sth ?

Comment: The difference is `struct A { A(int); explicit A(char); }; A a = 'a' /* OK */, b = {'a'} /* error */;`

Comment: Thank you for providing this reference that explains why the behaviour is observed. Yet, do you have some explanation regarding the rationale to specify the behaviour this way in the language ?

Comment: @T.C. I think I got what you meant.

Comment: @AdN Sorry I may not explain the rationale well; but in spite of the new C++11 feature list initialization, passing an argument to a function by value is always regarged as [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).